# How to implement In app Update for Android production bundle in Play Store

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, in-app-update

I have implemented In App Update in my app, its working fine in on both apk and bundle in Internal Testing but its not working when I Upload the production bundle in playstore, I do many scenarios in Internal testing and its working in all but not in live production bundle.

Comment: what type of error you are getting??

Comment: If your using firebase you have to update SHA certificate fingerprints in your Play console

Comment: @DeePanShu there is no any error the update dialog is not appears which is there when I upload bundle in Internal testing.

Comment: @GaneshMB I am not using firebase its my test app which i upload it to play console for testing it have only one activity which have update code and text.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in internal app sharing but not production could be similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72007256/18612003) where it turns out google app signing for production or test tracks means your app has a different signature and won't register an update.