# In app update in android always give UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app, app-update

I am using in-app update but it is not working in production. I tried various ways but could not resolve the issue. The code is in java for android studio project
My code is below:-

````
    private void checkUpdate() {

        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {

            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                    && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo);
            } else if  (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reached 2..  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo);
            } else if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()==UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    ```

Please tell me what is the mistake I am doing
````

Answer (score 1):

You have not created the code to force `App Update`. I also created code for app updates and mine is a `Flexible` update. Match your code with mine and make changes in your code or use my code to test your app.

```
private void inAppUpdate() {
        appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> task = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                try {
                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE, MainActivity.this, APP_UPDATE_CODE);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.d("Update", e.getMessage());
                }
            } else if (appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                snackPopup();
            }
        });
        appUpdateManager.registerListener(istListener);
    }
```

Let me know if my code does not work in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) for reminding me to either tailor my answer or suggest as possible duplicate. I'd agree with [@M-Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16765223/m-dev) you need to call `appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE, MainActivity.this, APP_UPDATE_CODE);` to start the update correctly.

You could also add appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener {} or appUpdateInfoTask.addOnCompleteListener to check that its successfully checking google play for new versions.

You should check that it works with internal App sharing.

[Please also see my post on how Google App signing can cause problems with in-app updates in production](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72007256/18612003)